# How to make some UI task asynchronously

Tags: wpf, multithreading, user-interface

I have some UI task which took to long. I have some 'home made' property grid ( I uses an ItemControl , where item template uses a ContentControl, the item itself holds the datatemplate to be used in the Content control.).

The application is Shapes viewer, where each shape has its properties. each time the user clicks on some shape, the property grid shows its properties (60 different properties).

The updates process takes something about 1-2 sec. while this updating the application freeze.

Is there any way to do the updating of the property grid in the background?
Is there any way to stop last updating?

Regards, Leon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement the MVVM pattern to make sure that your UI controls is a way to DISPLAY your data rather than be the HOLDER of data.

You can then choose to do various background tasks and only update VM content when ready.

Check out this video:

http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650

Comment: in my case, I used MVVM, My property grid (DataGid) displays Some VM list. The problem is that the UI updating tokes to much time

Answer (score 0):

you need to work with thread and dispatcher to do this.

Dispatcher in WPF/SL - http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher

In order to use another thread you have some options:

1. Threadpool (TaskClass only On .Net 4) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(v=vs.80).aspx
2. Thread class - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx
3. BackgroundWorker Class - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

The 3rd option is the easiest if you don't know how to work with threads.

I guess what taking so long is the fetching the properties so what you need to do is to perform the fetch in another thread and then to use Dispatcher in this thread to update your datagrid,
you have to use Dispatcher to update your GUI from another thread.

Comment: Thanks for your qiuck Replay... (תודה על התגובה המהירה)

My problem is that the UI Task (updaing DataGrid) takes to much time. until the updaing does not finish I can't do anything else with the UI.

Do you think that Threadpool/Threads/BackgroundWorker will let me solve this Issue?

Thanks agine

Comment: Dor, Sorry for being newbe. 
but I didn't understand the meaning of 'fetching'. did you mean to saperate the UI definition and data updating?
As much as i see, the hard part is the data grid updating

Comment: you need to open new thread, in this thread you need to get all data you want and then at the end use dispatcher to update the data grid

Comment: @leonnoah Why do you ask a question if you don't care about the answer?